# How to convert categorical label to continuous/numeric

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a newbie in Tensorflow and I need to convert my label from categorical to numerical because, later on my code, I will train using a linear regression model, which expects numbers at the labels.

My CSV file is like this below (the DDD column is the label):

```
AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD
3,2,A,N
4,2,B,N
5,3,A,N
3,3,A,S
3,3,A,N
```

My importing dataset code is below:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
train, eval = train_test_split(dataset,test_size=0.2,shuffle=False)

label_train = train.pop("DDD")
```

So, how do I iterate over `label_train` to change all "N" to "0" (number) and all "S" to "1" (number)? Is there a tensorflow function to do that?

NOTE:

I tried the code below however it keeps showing me the error `Name: DDD, dtype: object /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:30: SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy`

```
for chave1,valor1 in enumerate(label_train):
if label_train[chave1] == "N":
        label_train[chave1] = "0"
elif label_train[chave1] == "S":
        label_train[chave1] = "1"
else:
    print("Error HJ34.")
```

Comment: that's not an error, that's a warning.

Answer (score 0):

If the type of label_train is ndarray matrix:

```
idx = label_train=='N'
label_train[idx]=0
```